# How would you solve the Minimum Non Constructible Change problem with a Dynamic Programming Table?

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

this is the question I'm trying to solve using a dynamic programming table:

**We are given an array of positive integers, which represent the values of coins that we have in our possession. The array could have duplicates. We are asked to write a function that returns the minimum amount of change that we cannot create with our coins. For instance, if the input array is [1, 2, 5], the minimum amount of change that we cannot create is 4, since we can create 1, 2, 3 (1 + 2) and 5.**

The optimal solution is this:

```
def nonConstructibleChange(coins):
    coins.sort()
    minimum_change = 0
    for coin in coins:
        if coin > minimum_change + 1:
            break
        minimum_change += coin
    return minimum_change + 1
```

But I'd like to solve it using a brute force matrix type solution, because I feel like the optimal solution isn't something I would have thought of on my own. I want the rows represent the coins, and the columns represent the range of numbers from 1 to sum(coins).

Here's what I have so far, it's not even close to complete as I'm trying to learn dynamic programming:

```
def nonConstructibleChange(coins):
    coins = sorted(coins)
    if 1 not in coins:
        return 1
    if len(coins)==1:
        return 2
    sum_coins = sum(coins)

    array = [[0 for val in range(sum_coins)] for val in range(len(coins))]
    array[0][0]=1

    for val in range(len(coins)):
        coin = coins[val]
        for valtwo in range(sum_coins):
            if coin==valtwo+1:
                array[val][valtwo]=1
            else:
                if val!=0 and valtwo!=0 and valtwo<=val:
                    if array[val-1][valtwo-1]!=1 and array[val][valtwo-1]!=1 and array[val-1][valtwo]!=1:
                        return val-1
                    else:
                        array[val][valtwo]=1
```

Comment: I have no idea what you want to represent with that matrix. Can you explain in more detail what a value in that matrix would represent?

Comment: A value in the matrix would represent whether with that coin (row index) and the coins that came before it, the index of the column (minimum change) can be created. When the column index cannot be created by the coins seen previously, then that's the minimum change that can't be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get what you were trying to do with the `return val-1` statement, as that can only return a value from the set {0,1,...,n-2} where n is the number of coins, yet it is clear that the expected return value should often be (much) greater than the number of coins. For instance, for input [1,2,3] the expected return value is 7.

Secondly, I didn't quite get the relevance of using indexes `[valtwo-1]` and `[valtwo]` in that `if` condition: why would those two amounts (that differ by 1) have any relevance to the current coin?

I didn't look further to your code, but we can surely use your idea of a 0/1 list, and in each outer iteration bring in a next coin into the "game" to see which amounts can be paid.

But instead of a matrix that has a row per coin, use a 1-dimensional list of 0/1 values where (as you had) the index in the list represents a target amount and a 1 means that target amount can be paid with the coins that were considered so far. This list should have an index that is `sum(amount)+1` as that could be the least amount that is not payable. So the length of the list should be `sum(amount)+2`. That way we can be sure that after the algorithm has run, there will be at least one zero in this list -- at index `sum(amount)+1`.

The loop can look like this:

- For each coin (doesn't need to be in sorted order) do:

  - Iterate the list *backwards* to consider amounts in decreasing order

    - If we could already pay that amount (flag is 1) then we can add the current coin to that amount and flag that amount as payable too.

When all this is done we have flagged all amounts that can be paid. Remains to find the least amount for which we still have a 0 in the list.

Here is how that brute force algorithm would look:

```
def nonConstructibleChange(coins):
    sum_coins = sum(coins)

    canpay = [False] * (sum_coins + 2)  # 1-dimension is enough
    canpay[0] = True  # We can pay 0 without any coin

    for coin in coins:
        for amount in range(sum_coins + 1 - coin, -1, -1):  # backwards
            if canpay[amount]: # if we could pay this without the current coin
                canpay[amount + coin] = True  # ... then also we can pay this, using current coin
    # Get first amount that we cannot pay              
    return next(amount for amount, flag in enumerate(canpay) if not flag)
```

The iteration in backwards fashion is important as otherwise we risk using the same coin more than once.

Of course, this is not an efficient algorithm.